# Install drush using composer as vagrant user

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm using Vagrant with Ubuntu Trusty x64. I want to automate the installation of certain packages so I used Ansible as provisioner (I'm a beginner). Drush is one of the package I want to install and the recommended way to install Drush is using Composer. I have Composer installed correctly but not Drush. I want it to be installed on the vagrant user's home directory (where global composer packages are installed) but it gets installed on root user's home directory.

My `playbook.yml` looks like this:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  sudo: yes

  roles:
   - composer
   - drush
```

My drush's `main.yml` task looks like this:

```
---
- name: Install Drush
  remote_user: vagrant
  shell: composer global require drush/drush
```

My composer's `main.yml` task looks like this:

```
---
- name: Download Composer installer
  get_url: url=https://getcomposer.org/installer dest=/tmp/composer-installer.php mode=0755

- name: Run Composer installer
  shell: php composer-installer.php chdir=/tmp creates=/usr/local/bin/composer

- name: Make Composer accessible globally
  shell: mv /tmp/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer creates=/usr/local/bin/composer

- name: Add Composer's global packages to path
  copy: src=composer_envvar.sh dest=/etc/profile.d
```

Where the `composer_envvar.sh` contains the ff:

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

There must be a way to tell ansible to run the composer command as vagrant user.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into [Ansible's composer command](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/composer_module.html)?

But rather than relying on composer for Drush, you can now leverage the `drush.phar` file that ships with every release. It's very easy and straight forward.

Here's a sample task that checks if Drush is installed, and, if not, downloads the phar file, makes it executable and available in your `$PATH`:

```
---
- name: Check if Drush is installed
  stat:
    path: "{{ drush_path }}"
  register: drush

- name: Check Drush version
  shell: drush --version | awk '{print $4}' | head -n1
  register: drush_version_check
  when: drush.stat.exists == true

- name: Install Drush globally
  get_url:
    url: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/{{ drush_version }}/drush.phar
    dest: "{{ drush_path }}"
  when: drush.stat.exists == false or drush_version_check.stdout != "{{ drush_version }}"

- name: Make Drush executable
  file:
    path: "{{ drush_path }}"
    mode: 0755
  when: drush.stat.exists == true or drush_version_check.stdout != "{{ drush_version }}"
```

And then put `drush_path: /usr/local/bin/drush` in a `vars.yml` file in case you want to change the `$PATH` at a future point in time. `drush_version: 8.0.1` allows you to change the version to be installed when Drush gets updated.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this is a better way of installing Drush straight from its source rather than relying on Composer. I know Composer does its job well on most PHP packages/dependencies but it just wouldn't work on Drush in my case.